# how to release AVASSETEXPORTSESSION iOS

Tags: objective-c, avassetexportsession

i wrote the code like below and i am getting the memory leak at line:

```
 AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];
```

My Code is:

```
NSError *error;
AVMutableComposition* mixComposition = [AVMutableComposition composition];


NSURL*    audio_inputFileUrl = [_songPath valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;

NSString *video_inputFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"videoOutput1234videoOutput1234.mp4"];
NSLog(@"output url %@",video_inputFilePath);

NSURL*    video_inputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:video_inputFilePath];


NSArray *docPaths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docPath=[docPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* outputFilePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"OutPut.mov"];//[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"OutPut" ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL*    outputFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilePath];

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath]) 
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];
}
else {
    NSString *defaultPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"OutPut.mov"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:defaultPath toPath:outputFilePath error:&error];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];
}



CMTime nextClipStartTime = kCMTimeZero;

AVURLAsset* videoAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:video_inputFileUrl options:nil];
CMTimeRange video_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,videoAsset.duration);
AVMutableCompositionTrack *a_compositionVideoTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];

[a_compositionVideoTrack insertTimeRange:video_timeRange ofTrack:[[videoAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];


AVURLAsset* audioAsset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:audio_inputFileUrl options:nil];
CMTimeRange audio_timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, audioAsset.duration);
AVMutableCompositionTrack *b_compositionAudioTrack = [mixComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
[b_compositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:audio_timeRange ofTrack:[[audioAsset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0] atTime:nextClipStartTime error:nil];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath]) 
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];

AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough];   
_assetExport.outputFileType = @"com.apple.quicktime-movie";
_assetExport.outputURL = outputFileUrl;

if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:outputFilePath]) 
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:outputFilePath error:nil];

[_assetExport exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void ) {[self saveVideoToAlbum:outputFilePath]; }       ];    

[outputFileUrl release];
[videoAsset release];
[audioAsset release];
if (_assetExport.status == 2) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Exporting to library is completed" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK",nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
    [mixComposition release];
}
```

**when i tried to release AVASSETEXPORTSESSION my app is crashing and i don't have ay idea how to release this**

can you please tell me the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to release:

```
[outputFileUrl release];
[mixComposition release];
```

**Remove these lines from Your code.** You need to do that because You do not own them (not allocated). So You **do not need to release** them.

And then it should work now.

**Autorelease**:

```
AVAssetExportSession* _assetExport = [[[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mixComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough] autorelease];
```

or **release**:

```
[_assetExport release];
```